# returning 2 values , wrong output

Tags: c

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
int res [2] ;
 for (int i =0 ; i < numsSize ; i++){
   for (int j =0 ; j < numsSize ; j++){
        
      if (*(nums+i)+*(nums+j) == target ){
          res[0] = i ;
          res[1] = j ;
      }
   }
 };
//printf("[%d,%d]", res[0],res[1]);
return res;
```

}

This is the two sum problem . I am not getting the output correct . Can someone explain where I did wrong?

Comment: What results are you getting for what input values?

Comment: `res` ceases to exist after the `return`, The caller receives a pointer to memory that "does not exist". Pass the destination address or use `malloc()` (don't forget to `free()`)

Comment: You will need to explain the “two sum problem” and show some sample input data and the expected and actual output for that data. See [MCVE].

Comment: Unrelated: `*(nums+i)` is usually written as `nums[i]`. I find the *array syntax* easier on the eyes.

Comment: You've edited the question which invalidates most of the answers and comments. Does it work now with `malloc`?

Answer (score 1):

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
  int res [2] ;
  /* [...] */
  return res;
```

Well, `res` is a local variable stored on the `stack`. When the function is called, there is some space reserved on the stack to store `res` (push). When the function is returned this area is freed (pop) and other functions call reuse this space to store their own local variables.

For that reason, when you call `twoSum` the result is actually random. To return several values in `C`, the idiom is to provide as a `pointer` parameter:

```
void twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize, int* Sum1, int* Sum2){
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need 'returnSize' in 'toSum' function?
Because you receive the pointer as return value, you do not need to pass the int * parameter. And you can use pointer as array.
It is sufficient to do not forget to release memory of return value after you use it.
I suggest one sample like below:

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize - 1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < numsSize; j++){     //. j begins from i + 1 or not?
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target){   //. It is not need to use *(nums + i)
                int * returnSize = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
                if (returnSize == NULL){
                    return NULL;
                }
                returnSize[0] = i;
                returnSize[1] = j;

                return returnSize;
            }
        }
    }    
    return NULL;
}

int main() 
{
    int nums[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // sample data.
    int * result = twoSum(nums, 5, 4);
    if (result == NULL){
        printf("Failed");
    }
    else{
        printf("i: %d, j: %d", result[0], result[1]);       
        free(result);   //. don't forget this.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int* twoSum(){

  // I am a variable, I am declared on the stack...
  int res [2];

  // after this returns, the variable on the stack will be destroyed
  return res;
}

int main() {
  int* var = twoSum();

  // attempting to access var here will result in an invalid memory location :(
}
```

Your options here is either to return a struct:

```cpp
// declare a struct to hold result
typedef struct TwoSumResult {
  int a;
  int b;
} TwoSumResult;

TwoSumResult twoSum(){

  // now return as a struct
  return (TwoSumResult){ 42, 43 };
}
```

or use a function arg to return the result

```cpp
void twoSum(int res[2]){

   // set result
   res[0] = 42;
   res[1] = 43;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from leetcode - https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    
}
```

You must have noted this

> The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free()